# Why DataBinding is not propagating to UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, datatemplate, commandbinding

This morning I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835222/command-binding-is-not-propagating-for-control-into-a-datatemplate-of-itemtempla?noredirect=1#comment66965701_39835222) and doing a simple working sample gave me a different behavior than expected.

Full working sample at [GitHub](https://github.com/EricOuellet2/CommandRoutingIntoItemTemplate). Main partial code below.

In this present case, the command is never propagated to any UserControl, either if the UserControl is use directly as a child of the Window. It also not work if the UserControl is used as a DataTemplate for a ListBox ItemTemplate.

I also include a hack button to fix the problem where the Command reach the UserControls. The hack come from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099274/menuitem-in-window-commandbinding-in-usercontrol).

But using the hack does not explain why UserControl does not receive the Command (without it) and using this hack also break the first rule of good coding: "Hi cohesion and Low coupling". The hack should be used in the the window code in order for it to manage the Command in the UserControl, my thought is that it should happen by default.

Why the command is not propagating by default to the UserControl and what should I do to propagate the command to the UserControl in a clean way?

Note: Using only one CommandBinding (removing one or the other) in the UserControl does not fix the problem .

Partial code:

```
<Window x:Class="CommandRoutingIntoItemTemplate.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CommandRoutingIntoItemTemplate"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <local:UserControlTest></local:UserControlTest>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="2">
                        <local:UserControlTest></local:UserControlTest>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <ListBox.Items>
                <system:String>1</system:String>
                <system:String>2</system:String>
            </ListBox.Items>
        </ListBox>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Command="local:Commands.CommandTest">Put focus on TestBlock and click here to see if command occurs</Button>
            <Button Click="AddHack">Hack</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CommandRoutingIntoItemTemplate.UserControlTest"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CommandRoutingIntoItemTemplate"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="local:Commands.CommandTest" CanExecute="CommandTestCanExecuteUserControl" Executed="CommandTestExecuteUserControl"></CommandBinding>
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="UserControlTest">
            <TextBox.CommandBindings>
                <CommandBinding Command="local:Commands.CommandTest" CanExecute="CommandTestCanExecuteTextBox" Executed="CommandTestExecuteTextBox"></CommandBinding>
            </TextBox.CommandBindings>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are not getting commands invoked on your user control is that your buttons are not in separate focus scope. For WPF to pick up focused element for command target correctly, it needs to be in separate focus scope from command invoking control.

Framework will just traverse up visual tree from button looking for command bindings in their focus scope (in your case it won't find any). When framework does not find any command bindings in current focus scope, only then it looks into parent focus scope for focused element (In your case, buttons are in `Window` focus scope which has no parent scope so the search will end there).

Simply setting `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"` on your `StackPanel` will fix the issue.

You could also specify `CommandTarget` property on your buttons to point to your user control and not rely on focus.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks a lots! Works perfectly. Do you know if I can do something on the UserControl side in order to ensure that it will always work on each and every type of usage? Although it work fine now, I could want to use my UserControl elsewhere and I will have to remember that think. It sounds a better solution to write code at only one common place (UserControl) to ensure proper usage in every situations?

Comment: I also tested with menuItem, it works fine probably because Menu element has the fix you proposed to me: FocusManager.IsFocusScope set to true? That is something I have to know and remember ;-) ?

Comment: @EricOuellet That's exactly right. MenuItems are displayed in popups, which have their own focus scopes.